# Installing Java8 in Dockerfile

Tags: java, ubuntu, docker, java-8, dockerfile

I have a Docker container in which I was installing Java/JDK in order to power Pentaho. Starting at some point withing the last ~9 days ( I believe ), I've been getting an error when trying to build this container.

I'm not sure if the speciic jdk has been archived by oracle, but I've spent a solid day trying to find a way around this one and hitting dead ends.

Looking for a PPA or active dist to get me out of this mess.

From the Dockerfile:

```
# Pentaho
ENV PDI_RELEASE=6.1 \
    PDI_VERSION=6.1.0.1-196 \
    PDI_HOME=/opt/pentaho-di \
    KETTLE_HOME=/pentaho-di

# Java
# auto validate license
RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list && \
    echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer unzip && \
    apt-get clean && \
    curl -sS -L -o /tmp/pdi-ce-${PDI_VERSION}.zip http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pentaho/Data%20Integration/${PDI_RELEASE}/pdi-ce-${PDI_VERSION}.zip && \
    unzip -q /tmp/pdi-ce-${PDI_VERSION}.zip -d $PDI_HOME && \
    rm /tmp/pdi-ce-${PDI_VERSION}.zip
```

Here's the failure I'm getting from the build:

```
2018-01-18T17:59:31.674ZUnpacking locales (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:32.569ZSelecting previously unselected package oracle-java8-installer.
2018-01-18T17:59:32.571ZPreparing to unpack .../oracle-java8-installer_8u151-1~webupd8~0_all.deb ...
2018-01-18T17:59:32.742Zdebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2018-01-18T17:59:32.966Zoracle-license-v1-1 license has already been accepted
2018-01-18T17:59:32.983ZUnpacking oracle-java8-installer (8u151-1~webupd8~0) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:33.245ZProcessing triggers for mime-support (3.58) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:33.636ZProcessing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:33.644ZProcessing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.3-1) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:36.221ZSetting up java-common (0.52) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:36.333ZSetting up locales (2.19-18+deb8u10) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:36.421Zdebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2018-01-18T17:59:36.839ZGenerating locales (this might take a while)...
2018-01-18T17:59:36.842ZGeneration complete.
2018-01-18T17:59:36.877ZSetting up oracle-java8-installer (8u151-1~webupd8~0) ...
2018-01-18T17:59:36.969Zdebconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2018-01-18T17:59:37.411ZNo /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc file found.
Creating /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc and
using default oracle-java8-installer wgetrc settings for it.
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
2018-01-18T17:59:38.406Z--2018-01-18 17:59:38--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.488Z184.84.129.202
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.84.129.202|:80... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.488Zconnected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.490Z302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2018-01-18 17:59:38--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz
2018-01-18T17:59:38.501ZResolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.635Z23.212.176.23, 2600:1408:10:397::2d3e, 2600:1408:10:3b5::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|23.212.176.23|:443... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.636Zconnected.
2018-01-18T17:59:38.644ZHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.738Z302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516298498_6fba300d1f634adc9f84ee54d5966fce [following]
--2018-01-18 17:59:38--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/jdk-8u151-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1516298498_6fba300d1f634adc9f84ee54d5966fce
2018-01-18T17:59:38.738ZConnecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|184.84.129.202|:80... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.739Zconnected.
2018-01-18T17:59:38.739ZHTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
2018-01-18T17:59:38.758Z404 Not Found
2018-01-18 17:59:38 ERROR 404: Not Found.

2018-01-18T17:59:38.808Zdownload failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
```

A workaround I've been trying per SO and the internets' guidance:

```
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get update
RUN cd /var/lib/dpkg/info && \
    sed -i 's|JAVA_VERSION=8u151|JAVA_VERSION=8u161|' oracle-java8-installer.* && \
    sed -i 's|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u151-b12/e758a0de34e24606bca991d704f6dcbf/|PARTNER_URL=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u161-b12/2f38c3b165be4555a1fa6e98c45e0808/|' oracle-java8-installer.* && \
    sed -i 's|SHA256SUM_TGZ="c78200ce409367b296ec39be4427f020e2c585470c4eed01021feada576f027f"|SHA256SUM_TGZ="6dbc56a0e3310b69e91bb64db63a485bd7b6a8083f08e48047276380a0e2021e"|' oracle-java8-installer.* && \
    sed -i 's|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_151|J_DIR=jdk1.8.0_161|' oracle-java8-installer.*
RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java8-installer unzip
```

Unfortunately it looks like the jessie dist is missing -- here's the error:

```
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) OK
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie InRelease
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Ign http://deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release.gpg
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Hit http://deb.debian.org jessie Release
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie Release
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps)
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps)
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps)
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps)
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps) Err http://ppa.launchpad.net jessie/main amd64 Packages
(image: pre-deps) (service: rails_pre_deps)   404  Not Found
```

Apologies for the differences in output. One is coming from `jet`, and the other is from codeship.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Trusty is already very old release. Can't you base your docker image on at least Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Then openjdk8 would be included in default repo.